# count() function in python does not count repeated occurence

Tags: python

I recently came across the count function python. I got a question.
It works fine for the below example:

Input: String: `rrr`  Substring: `rr`

Output: 1

So when I count the number of time the substring appear it works.
But what I want to know is what if I want to count the repetition of substring.
For example,

Input: String: `rrr`  Substring: `rr`

Output: 2

Here it considers the repeated character in the substring,
Given: `rrr`

Here `r` is mid character hence
It pairs it as `rr` and `rr`. So the output is 2.

Hope you understand my doubt.

Thank you

Comment: @Barmar I think the OP wants to count *overlapping* occurrences of a substring, but `str.count` only counts *non-overlapping* occurrences

Comment: @Barmar I think they mean that is the output they would desire, not the output they are actually etting.

Comment: His second output is an example of his DESIRED output.  He didn't word it clearly.

Comment: Yeah, he didn't need to repeat the inputs, that's what confused me.

Comment: Thank you all. Now I understood how to count the overlapping occurrences. Once again thanks for clearing the doubt.